# HQL: Help in preforming join

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a entity by name Project.

```
public class Project {

@EmbeddedId
private ProjectID id;

@Column(name="updated_at")
private Date updatedAt;

@Column(name="sys_updated_at")
private Date sysUpdatedAt;

@OneToOne(optional=true, mappedBy="project", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private SysProject sysProject;
}
```

As you can see it has one to one relation with "SysProject"

```
public class SysProject extends BaseSysEntity implements Serializable {

@OneToOne(optional=true, fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="sysClientId", referencedColumnName="sysClientId"),
    @JoinColumn(name="pProject", referencedColumnName="pProject")
})
private Project project;

@Column(name="sysupdate")
private Date sysupdate;


public Project getProject() {
    return project;
}

public void setProject(Project project) {
    this.project = project;
}
}
```

Now i want to write an HQL query which satisfies two conditions.

1) All projects for which SysProject is null.

2) All project which have SysProject but Project.updatedAt != SysProject.sysupdate

I have written following query but it only returns Items which meet point (2)

```
SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE (NOT EXISTS (SELECT s FROM p.sysProject s)) OR (p.sysProject.id IS NOT NULL AND p.sysProject.sysupdate != p.updatedAt)
```

When i remove following part from query it meet point (1):

(p.sysProject.id IS NOT NULL AND p.sysProject.sysupdate != p.updatedAt)

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
String hql = "FROM Project WHERE sysProject IS NULL OR (sysProject.id IS NOT NULL AND sysProject.sysupdate != updatedAt)";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List<Project> projects = query.list();
```

Comment: For your information "FROM Project WHERE sysProject IS NULL" never works when there is one to one mapping.